# how to extract before and after substring in a string using python3

Tags: python-3.x

I am having a string like `"123/abc/${TEST}/ABCD/"`. I need to extract two strings before and after a "/${" and "}" in two variables.

## Expected output is

```
string1 = 123/abc
string2 = /ABCD/
```

Comment: `string1, string2 = "123/abc/${TEST}/ABCD/".split("${TEST}")` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `re.split` on the pattern `/\$\{.*?\}`:

```
inp = "123/abc/${TEST}/ABCD/"
parts = re.split(r'/\$\{.*?\}', inp)
print(parts)
```

This prints:

```
['123/abc', '/ABCD/']
```

We could make this more specific by spitting on `/${TEST}` exactly, or we could even let `TEST` come from a string variable.